# Cumulative Totals for each month of the last 3 months

Tags: powerbi, dax

I managed to create following table with DAX:

[image: Current Result]

Using the following DAX:

```
Two Months Running Total = 
VAR _twomonthbeforetoday    = DATE( YEAR( TODAY() ), MONTH( TODAY() ) -2, 1 )
VAR _monthend               = IF( MONTH( MAX( DimDate[Date] ) ) = MONTH( _twomonthbeforetoday ), MAX( DimDate[Date] ), BLANK() )
RETURN
CALCULATE( [Cumulative Sales],
FILTER( ALL( DimDate ), DimDate[Date] >= _twomonthbeforetoday && DimDate[Date] <= _monthend))

Previous Month Running Total = 
VAR _previousmonth  = DATE( YEAR( TODAY() ), MONTH( TODAY() ) -1, 1 )
VAR _monthend       = IF( MONTH( MAX( DimDate[Date] ) ) = MONTH( _previousmonth ), MAX( DimDate[Date] ), BLANK() )
RETURN
CALCULATE( [Cumulative Sales],
FILTER( ALL( DimDate ), DimDate[Date] >= _previousmonth && DimDate[Date] <= _monthend))

This Month Running Total = 
VAR _today          = DATE( YEAR( TODAY() ), MONTH( TODAY() ), 1 )
VAR _monthend       = IF( MONTH( MAX( DimDate[Date] ) ) = MONTH( _today ), MAX( DimDate[Date] ), BLANK() )
RETURN
CALCULATE( [Cumulative Sales],
FILTER( ALL( DimDate ), DimDate[Date] >= _today && DimDate[Date] <= _monthend))
```

However, when I remove the Month column, I get the following:

[image: Unexpected Results]

How would I alter my DAX to show it to me like this:

[image: Expected Results]

I can't seem to get it right. Please can you assist?

Herewith are the data fields in this table:

[image: Current Data Fields]

Comment: How is your table created? Is it a Calculated Table? If so, please share DAX expression. What is the DAX for the `[Cumulative Sales]` measure? Also share your data model (relationship diagram).

Comment: No this is a normal table in Power BI with the DimDate[CalendarDay] & Month with 4 Measures (BaseAmount and the other 3 mentioned above)

Comment: I've updated my question with the data fields in the table... @SamNseir

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
This Month Running Total = 
  var monthStart = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1)
  var monthEnd = EOMONTH(monthStart, 0)
  var monthCurDay = DATE( YEAR(monthStart), MONTH(monthStart), SELECTEDVALUE('DimDate'[CalendarDay], DAY(monthEnd)) )
  
  var result = CALCULATE(
    [Cumulative Sales],
    FILTER(ALL(DimDate), monthStart <= DimDate[Date] && DimDate[Date] <= monthCurDay && monthCurDay <= monthEnd)
  )

  RETURN SWITCH(TRUE(),
    ISINSCOPE(DimDate[CalendarDay]) && monthCurDay > TODAY(), BLANK(),
    result
  )


Previous Month Running Total = 
  var monthStart = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) - 1, 1)
  var monthEnd = EOMONTH(monthStart, 0)
  var monthCurDay = DATE( YEAR(monthStart), MONTH(monthStart), SELECTEDVALUE('DimDate'[CalendarDay], DAY(monthEnd)) )
  
  var result = CALCULATE(
    [Cumulative Sales],
    FILTER(ALL(DimDate), monthStart <= DimDate[Date] && DimDate[Date] <= monthCurDay && monthCurDay <= monthEnd)
  )
  RETURN result


Two Months Running Total = 
  var monthStart = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()) - 2, 1)
  var monthEnd = EOMONTH(monthStart, 0)
  var monthCurDay = DATE( YEAR(monthStart), MONTH(monthStart), SELECTEDVALUE('DimDate'[CalendarDay], DAY(monthEnd)) )
  
  var result = CALCULATE(
    [Cumulative Sales],
    FILTER(ALL(DimDate), monthStart <= DimDate[Date] && DimDate[Date] <= monthCurDay && monthCurDay <= monthEnd)
  )
  RETURN result
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?